# NodeJS Queue performing delayed HTTP Request are weird

Tags: node.js, http, request, queue

Dear helpful people in the internet,
i started to write an HTTP Queue. I have a **Request** Class, which **works if I use it without context**, but with my queue active, my http requests wont work. I can't figure out why.

```
var t = new Request('s','s', function(){});
t.perform();
```

When i perform the request like this in any file. It works. But when i use it with my queue (index.js,L19 to L22) no request is performed. The function **Request.perform()** were executed, but the HTTP-Request isn't there.
Sorry for my english, I'm not native ^^

**index.js**

```
const http    = require('http');
const https   = require('https');
const {Request} = require('./classes/Request');
const queue   = require('./queue.js');

queue.setCallbackFunction(performRequest);
function performRequest(request){
    console.log("2");
    request.perform();
}
var req = new Request('','', function(response,body){
   console.log(JSON.stringify(response) + " :: " + body);
});
queue.add(req);
```

**queue.js**

```
var queue = [];
var ratelimits = [];

module.exports.add = function(request){
    queue.push(request);
    run_queue();
}
module.exports.setCallbackFunction = function(cb){
    call = cb;
}
module.exports.setRateLimits = function(ratelimitings){
    ratelimits = [];
    for(var z in ratelimitings){
        var x = ratelimitings[z];
        var data = {};
        data.max = x[0];
        data.time = x[1];
        data.count = 0;

        ratelimits[x[1]] = data;
    }
}
function run_queue(){
    var q;
    if(queue.length > 0){
        q = run_request(queue[0]);
        while (q == true) {
            queue.shift();
            if(queue.length > 0)
            q = run_request(queue[0]);
        }
    }
}

function run_request(request){
    for(var z in ratelimits){
        var x = ratelimits[z];
        if(x.max <= x.count){
            return false;
        }
    }
    for(var z in ratelimits){
        var x = ratelimits[z];
        if(x.count === 0){
            setTimeout(function(z){
                console.log(JSON.stringify(x));
                ratelimits[z].count = 0;
                run_queue();
            },z,z);
        }
        x.count++;
        //console.log(JSON.stringify(x));
    }
    //DO REQUEST
    console.log("1")
    call(request);
    return true;
}
```

**Request.js**

```
exports.Request = class{
    constructor(host,path,cb){
        this.path = path;
        this.cb = cb;
        this.host = host
    }
    perform(){
        console.log("3");
        var https = require('https');
        var options = {
            host: 'www.example.com',
            path: '/'
        };

        var callback = function(response) {
        //HERE THIS GETS NEVER CALLED BECAUSE OF WHATEVER WHILE ITS IN THE QUEUE
            var str = '';
        //another chunk of data has been recieved, so append it to `str`
            response.on('data', function (chunk) {
                str += chunk;
            });

            //the whole response has been recieved, so we just print it out here
            response.on('end', function () {
                console.log(str);
            });
        }

        https.request(options, callback).end();
    }
}
```

All 3 console.logs get printed, but the Request Callback Never gets called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is caused by function `run_queue`:

```
function run_queue(){
    var q;
    if(queue.length > 0){
        q = run_request(queue[0]);
        while (q == true) {
            queue.shift();
            if(queue.length > 0)
            q = run_request(queue[0]);
        }
    }
}
```

After `run_request()` is executed successfully (HTTP request is sent), `queue.shift()` is called immediately, which means the `req` object you just added into the queue is removed from `queue` array and qualified for Garbage Collection. As one HTTP request/response will normally cost a few milliseconds, it is very likely that before response is retrieved, the `req` object is GCed (destroyed). Thus, no callback will be invoked, as the HTTP connection does not exist any more.

To change queue but keep `req` object from GC, you need to save it somewhere else, such as a temporary array (the infinite loop bug is also fix in following code):

```
var tmp = [];
function run_queue(){
    var q;
    if(queue.length > 0){
        q = run_request(queue[0]);
        while (q == true) {
            tmp.push(queue.shift());
            if(queue.length > 0) {
                q = run_request(queue[0]);
            } else {
                q = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Please note the above code is only for demo. In production code, you need to manage the `tmp` array -- when one request is done, it needs to be removed from `tmp`. Otherwise, `tmp` array will keep growing...

Comment: Thank you!  I will try this. Sounds logic to me.

Comment: no... doesn't work... Sorry. But thank you for your help

Comment: hmmm...@qry, I've created a full example in http://code.runnable.com/WRHaYmRs9Od72wFx/queue_example-for-node-js-and-hello-world , after run it, you can see the html content of caniuse.com is printed in console (Request callback gets called). Wish it is helpful.